# Can't resolve promise returned by Immediately Invoked Async Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, iife

I'm trying to assign a variable to an immediately invoked async function but cannot resolve the promise it returns.

```
const user: any = (async () => {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(await redis.get(email) || '{}')
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Failed to parse JSON of redis value, error:', error)
            return {}
        }
    })().then(token => {return token})
```

`console.log(user)` prints `Promise { <pending> }`, I've read all the answers on here related to this subject and can't figure out how to make this work, if it's even possible/ advisable. Thanks.

Comment: If you wrap your code in a main async function, then you can await your IIAFE (or not use it at all), without it you cant await a promise before your console.log fires

Comment: @LawrenceCherone wow thanks! It actually was in an async function, I should've included that. I didn't realize I could simply put await before the IIAFE.